# Why can I not pass this comparison function as a template argument?

Tags: c++, stl, std

I am trying to create an std::set with a function I defined for sorting,
but I get the error: "Error: function "GFX::MeshCompare" is not a type name"

Mesh.h

```
namespace GFX
{
    struct Mesh
    {
        [...]
    };

    inline bool MeshCompare(const Mesh& a, const Mesh& b)
    {   
        return ( (a.pTech < b.pTech) ||
                 ( (b.pTech == a.pTech) && (a.pMaterial < b.pMaterial) ) ||
                 ( (b.pTech == a.pTech) && (a.pMaterial == b.pMaterial) && (a.topology < b.topology) ) 
               );
    }
};
```

Renderer.h

```
namespace GFX
{
    class Renderer
    {
    private:
        [...]
        std::set<Mesh, MeshCompare> m_Meshes;

    };
};
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: @Als I tried qualifying it fully, but no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second template argument to `std::set` has to be a *type*, not *value* .

If you want to use function (which is *value*, not *type*), then you've to pass it as argument to the constructor, which means you can do this:

```
class Renderer
{
    typedef bool (*ComparerType)(Mesh const&,Mesh const&);

    std::set<Mesh, ComparerType> m_Meshes;
public:
     Renderer() : m_Meshes(MeshCompare) 
     {        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ note this
     }
};
```

---

Or, define a functor class, and pass this as second *type* argument to `std::set`.

```
struct MeshComparer
{   
    bool operator()(const Mesh& a, const Mesh& b) const
    {
             return ( (a.pTech < b.pTech) ||
             ( (b.pTech == a.pTech) && (a.pMaterial < b.pMaterial) ) ||
             ( (b.pTech == a.pTech) && (a.pMaterial == b.pMaterial) && (a.topology < b.topology) ) );
   }
};
```

And then use it:

```
std::set<Mesh, MeshComparer> m_Meshes;
```

Comment: reference tells me I can also pass a function? And if I go to the definition of std::set I can't find an explicit "typename", so I don't get what's causing the trouble?

Comment: @xcrypt: There is a difference between *template argument* and *function/constructor argument*. See my answer.

Comment: Well do you know std::foreach()? You can pass a function or a functor there, as far as I know a template parameter isn't able to put a restriction on that, only a function parameter can. Do you know *why* this is not working?
EDIT: I should ask my question differently: Do you know *why* you cannot pass a value?

Comment: @xcrypt: `std::for_each` is function template, which can accept any *callable* entity as third argument, which means you can pass function  pointer as well as functor *object*. Note that it is the object you pass, not the class.

Comment: @xcrypt: See the definition of `std::set`. It is a class template: `template<class Key, class Compare = std::less<Key>,class Allocator = std::allocator<Key> > class set;` ... that is, all the template arguments are *types*.

Comment: But a class template can also accept a value as a template argument... I don't get what is causing the problem *technically*. EDIT: Ah, so the keyword "class" before a template parameter means that you cannot pass a value/function pointer?

Comment: @xcrypt: It depends on the definition of the class template. If you define a class template like this : `template<Fun fun> class Example{};` where `Fun` is defined as `typedef void (*Fun)();` then you can pass a function pointer to `Example` as : `Example<f> e;` where `f` is a function defined as `void f() {}`.

Comment: I believe you, but then, the question still arises why it *does* work with `template<class InputIterator, class Function>
  Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f)`? The class keyword is used there.

Comment: @xcrypt: In case of `for_each`, you pass argument to the function as *function argument*, not as *template argument*. You don't write `for_each<a,b,c>()`. You write `for_each(a,b,c)`. That is why I told you in the beginning that there is huge difference between the two. Try to understand the difference.

Comment: I understand it now. The keyword 'class' preceding a template parameter just means that you can't pass a value. It just defines a type. The variable 'f' defines the value, which must be of the type 'Function' (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @xcrypt: Yes. When a template definition uses the keyword `class` or `typename`, then it asks you to pass *type*, but when it uses an already defined type, such as `int` or `Fun`, then it asks you to pass a value to the template as *template argument*. But in case of *value* as *template argument*, the C++ Standard only allows you to use integral values : which includes, `int`, long`, `char`, `enum`, etc, including function addresses (which are always integral values); you cannot pass `float`, `double`, and other class objects.

Comment: Ok, why didn't you say that from the beginning. But thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want to use a functor, you can use a pointer to function:

```
std::set<Mesh, bool(*)(Mesh const&, Mesh const&)> set(MapCompare);
```

(In this example code I'm constructing an object named `set`, this is not a class data member.)