# Implicit conversion to comparison function object (functor) for std::sort but not std::map?

Tags: c++

I have been using `std::sort` with a function as comparison function. The function is implicitly converted to a functor (by GCC). I tried the same when declaring a `std::map` type, but this fails.

[Compiling](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b24187608335e9d8) with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++14 -pedantic`:

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct S { int i; };
struct Payload { bool b; };

bool compare(const S* const& lhs, const S* const& rhs)
{
    return lhs->i < rhs->i;
}

using MyMap = std::map<const S*, Payload, compare>;

static void foo([[maybe_unused]] const MyMap&) {}

int main()
{
    std::vector<const S*> vs;
    std::sort(vs.begin(), vs.end(), compare); // OK

    MyMap m;
    foo(m);
}
```

This is the output:

```
main.cpp:13:50: error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::map'
   13 | using MyMap = std::map<const S*, Payload, compare>;
      |                                                  ^
main.cpp:13:50: note:   expected a type, got 'compare'
```

Is there a way I can pass a functor to the `map` declaration without the need to manually defining a functor class (as it is possible with `std::sort`)?

Comment: Later I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9341781/5534993) similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up types and values. The third argument to `std::sort` is a value, the third argument to `std::map` is a type.

```
using MyMap = std::map<const S*, Payload, bool (*)(const S* const&, const S* const&)>;
```

is prefectly legal.

Then you could write

```
MyMap my_map(compare);
```

PS there's no implicit conversion to a functor going on in your sort example. As a template function sort can be called with anything which is legal with a function call operator. That includes functors and function pointers (among other things).

Comment: You can make it a bit more readable by using `decltype(&compare)`.